# How do I use auto with push_back with an initializerlist?

Tags: c++, auto

By initializer list I mean {"something", "like", "this"}. I looked on the web and could not find any example of this.

```
DoublyLinkedList( std::initializer_list<T> & list)
{
    for (auto T& f : list)
        push_back(f);
}
```

Comment: Missing a `template<typename T>` prefixed to your function?

Comment: `auto T` tries to make a variable named `T`. The compiler chokes on the rest of the line (`& f : list`) because it makes no sense after the variable definition.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant:

```
for (auto& f : list)
```

also instead of `std::initializer_list<T> &` (pass by reference) use `std::initializer_list<T>` (pass by value), this way you will be able to use your constructor as follows:

```
DoublyLinkedList({1,2,3});
```

this is because copying initializer_list does not make a copy of the underlaying array of elements.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to initialize some container with the values passed within `std::initializer_list`. In this case, you are just reading the `list` without modifying it - so no need for copying when it's passed to the function/method (`..( std::initializer_list<T> list)`) and also no need for passing it by reference (`..( std::initializer_list<T>& list)`). Instead you pass it by constant reference (`..( std::initializer_list<T> const& list)`) avoiding unnecessary copy and preventing its modification.

Then, when you iterate through the list within range-based for-loop, again you need to only read elements. Therefore, you avoid extra copy (`&`) and also prevent modification of the element (`const`). BTW, the compiler would prevent modification of the elements anyways, due to the argument modifiers in the function/method declaration.

`auto` is the type specifier denoting that the actual type will be automatically deduced from its initializer. You could simply use `T` instead.

Below is simple example pushing to the local vector and returning # of pushed elements.

```
template<typename T>
size_t DoublyLinkedList( std::initializer_list<T> const& list)
{
    std::vector<T> vec;
    for (auto const& element : list)
        vec.push_back(element);

    // if all you need is to initialize std container with the list:
    // std::vector<T> vec(list);

    return vec.size();
}

int main() {
    cout << "# int elements pushed: " << DoublyLinkedList({1,2,3}) << endl;
    cout << "# string elements pushed: " << DoublyLinkedList({"something", "like", "this"}) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

stdout:

*# elements pushed: 3*

*# string elements pushed: 3*

Comment: Interesting fun fact and caveat: Those string elements aren't `strings`.

Comment: By the way, almost a good answer here, but currently this is more a proof of concept than an answer. You need a bit of explaining on what you're doing differently and why.

Comment: well, it's `const char*`, but I didn't say that it's `std::string` - just "string" :)